# Issue in Json RPC with mod_perl

Tags: json, apache, perl

I am having an issue with Json RPC and mod_perl. I am trying to return a value from a cgi script which is running in Apache through mod_perl. But in the return value, following apache headers are automatically added and therefore I am not able to access the return value from my client script.

```
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

In my Apache configuration file I have following directives.

```
LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
PerlSwitches -w
PerlSwitches -T
Alias /perl /var/www/html/perl
<Directory /var/www/html/perl>
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

My cgi script is pasted below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use JSON::RPC::Server::CGI;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my $server = JSON::RPC::Server::CGI->new;

$server->dispatch('Myapp')->handle();
```

The Myapp.pm is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Myapp;
use base qw(JSON::RPC::Procedure); # Perl 5.6 or more than
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
sub test : Public(u1:str){
        my ($s, $obj) = @_;
        my $u1 = $obj->{u1};
        return $u1;
}
1;
```

My client side script is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON::RPC::Client;
use Data::Dumper;
my $client = new JSON::RPC::Client;
my $uri = 'http://IP/perl/test.cgi';  
$client->prepare($uri, ['test']);
$str= $client->test('testing');
print "$str\n\n";
```

In normal case the output should be **testing** . But in my case I am getting the below error.

```
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "Status: 200\r\nConte...") at /usr/local/share/perl5/JSON/RPC/Client.pm line 186
```

The issue is because some http headers are automatically get added to the return value. Is there any way to suppress these headers?

Note: Kindly don't recommend normal cgi scripts or running perl script as daemon because it is already working and tested from my end. We are using mod_perl for high performance.

Comment: What extra headers are being added? Can you show a complete example of the output?